# (Image fader) fade color & 1 duplicate fade

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

First off, i just started HTML,CSS and JS and i'm currently teaching myself!(so i'm a newbie!)

Now, i made a fullscreen image fader using jQuery and i ran into 2 small problems.

**1)** Fader shows (img 1) then it fades to (img 1) ***again*** and then it fades to (img 2) (img 
3) (img 4) and back to (img 1).
But i'm looking for a simple (img 1) > (img 2) > (img 3) > (img 4) > (img 1) rotation.

**2)** While (img 1) fades into (img 2) a short but very bright white flash appears and im looking to change that into a more subtle black flash or even change it into the next (img) straight away!

Thanks for reading i'm hoping you can understand me i can't explain it any clearer as im not really experienced (yet).

**Here's the code i used!**

```
    $(document).ready(function functionName() {

    var count = 0;
    var images = ["slider1","slider2","slider3","slider4"];
    var image = $(".fader");

    image.css("background-image","url("+images[count]+")");

    setInterval(function(){
    image.fadeOut(500, function(){
    image.css("background-image","url("+images[count++]+")");
    image.fadeIn(500);
    });
    if(count == images.length)
    {
    count = 0;
    }

    },10000);

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

The first issue is that you are actually loading the first image twice. You set `count` to `0` and set the background image. Then in your loop, the first thing that happens is that it sets the background image to image `0` again, *and then* increments `count` to `1` (you are using the post-increment operator). If you want to increment first, use the pre-increment operator (`++count`). But you will need to be careful, as that changes your check to see when `count` goes beyond the image array length.

I can't be 100% sure as to what is causing the flash, but my guess is that since you are using the same element and just setting the background image, when you replace the first image with the second image it takes a second for it to download, so you see the background for that period of time. Once you get through all images, they are in memory so you wouldn't see the flash again. The fix for that is to either preload all images or to load the next image in an element and place it on top of the old image, then fade it in.

These things are fixable, but you may also want to check out one of many image slideshow plugins out there. Many use jQuery, but not all, and you can customize them quite a bit. It would probably save you some hassle.

#### EDIT

Let's just make this simpler, since you already have the basics in there. Here is some updated code:

```
$(document).ready(function functionName () {
    var count = 0;
    var images = ["slider1","slider2","slider3","slider4"];
    var image = $(".fader");

    image.css("background-image","url("+images[count]+")");
    var count = 1;

    setInterval(function () {
        image.fadeOut(500, function () {
            image.css("background-image","url("+images[count++]+")");
            image.fadeIn(500);
        });
        if (count == images.length) {
            count = 0;
        }
    }, 10000);
});
```

The only change I made was to set `count` to `1` after the first image is set; that way, when the interval starts it will start with `1` but will loop back to `0` when it gets to the end.

As for your comment about the white flash, yes, it is most likely the fact that the background is white and you are going down to 0 and back up again. If you want less of a flash, you could change the background color of the div to black or a medium grey or something like that. If you want to get rid of it completely, you would need to move to a different strategy, where you have a second image that is overlayed over the first one, the new one gets faded in, and then the bottom one can be removed and another new one can go on top of the second one. You are always fading from one image to another instead of an image down to nothing and back.